# $bn1("#ma-bestsellerpro-slider").jcarousel is not a function

Tags: jquery, magento, jcarousel

I'm having trouble getting jcarousel to work am I missing something. Link below.

http://testing.digital-results.com/worldofbaths/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to have several jQuery identifiers. I noticed $jqv and $bn1, and the $bn1 seems to be the one that breaks. Have you tried switching $bn1 to $jqv?

Comment: Yea seems to initialise jcarousel using $jqv, confusing though cos in the slider.js file I thought jcarousel was extending $bn1?